# How to convert CharSequence to UTF-8 encoded byte array in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a `CharSequence` to a UTF-8 encoded `byte[]` array.

And i've been having problems with it, so i was going to ask stackoverflow for help. And i was going to write a *Java Fiddle* to do it:

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/3MliN0HgwDD

Except the fiddle itself doesn't work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.charset;

// The main method must be in a class named "Main".
class Main {
    public static byte[] charSequenceToUtf8(final CharSequence input)
    {
        //char[] chars = new char[input.length];
        //for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++)
        //  chars[i] = input.charAt(i);

        CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(input);
        checkEquals(10, charBuffer.length(), "Charbuffer is wrong length");

        Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); 
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = cs.encode(charBuffer);
        checkEquals(10, byteBuffer.length(), "byteBuffer is wrong length");
        
        byte[] utf8 = byteBuffer.array();        
        checkEquals(10, utf8.length, "utf8 bytes is wrong length");
    }
    
    public static void checkEquals(int expected, int actual, String message)
    {
        if (expected == actual)
            return;
            
        String sExpected = String.valueOf(expected);
        String sActual = String.valueOf(actual);
        
        throw new Exception("Test failed. Expected "+sExpected+", Actual "+sActual+". "+message);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("AAAAAAAAAA"); //ten A's
    }
}
```

It seems that `java.nio` requires at least Java 7 <sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029271/cannot-find-package-java-nio-file)</sup>. Which is why it is confusing to me that it doesn't work in Java 16:

[image]

So this bring up a lot of questions:

- how can i convert a `CharSequence` to a `byte[]` array? <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514836/how-to-encode-a-charsequence-using-a-charset-without-converting-to-string)</sup>
- why does it not work in Java 16?

In the end, the actual bug is that trying to encode the string `AAAAAAAAA` returns an 11-element array:

| CharSequence | UTF-8 byte array |
| --- | --- |
| *"AA"* | `[65, 65]` |
| *"AAA"* | `[65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAAAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAAAAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAAAAAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]` |
| *"AAAAAAAAAA"* | `[65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 0]` |

Why is the above code, that i stole from the linked question, failing of a string of 10 characters?

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. Don't know _why_, but it appears encoding `"AAAAAAAAAA"` returns a `ByteBuffer` whose **capacity** is `11`, but its **limit** is set to `10`. You're printing out the entire backing array without taking the limit into account.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? What's wrong with just doing `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`?

Comment: Typo in `import java.nio.charset;`, no class name

Comment: In addition to @DuncG comment, there is no reason to have `import java.lang.*;`. In Java, that import is implicitly present in all source files.

Comment: @Sweeper [**CharSequence**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) doesn't have a `.getBytes()` method

Comment: @Slaw For that you can either blame `mycompiler.io`. (not that it matters at all)

Comment: A `ByteBuffer` is not equivalent to a `CharSequence`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that if you have a `String`, then you can simply do:

```java
byte[] bytes = theString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Or, even if you have a `CharSequence`, you can do:

```java
byte[] bytes = theCharSequence.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

That will potentially create a `String` *copy* of the `CharSequence` if it's not already a `String`, though it should be quickly garbage collected.

But regarding your question, you're not taking the `ByteBuffer`'s [limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit()) (or [position](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#position()), though it's `0` in this case) into account. For whatever reason, encoding `"AAAAAAAAAA"` results in a buffer whose **capacity** is `11`, but whose **limit** is `10`. But the `#array()` method returns the entire backing array, regardless of the buffer's position or limit. This means you need to manually take the limit (and position) into account when converting the `ByteBuffer` to a `byte[]`.

For example:

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      String string = "A".repeat(i);

      CharBuffer chars = CharBuffer.wrap(string);
      ByteBuffer bytes = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(chars);

      System.out.printf("%-10s | %s%n", string, Arrays.toString(toByteArray(bytes)));
    }
  }

  public static byte[] toByteArray(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    byte[] array = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(buffer.position(), array);
    return array;
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
A          | [65]
AA         | [65, 65]
AAA        | [65, 65, 65]
AAAA       | [65, 65, 65, 65]
AAAAA      | [65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
AAAAAA     | [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
AAAAAAA    | [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
AAAAAAAA   | [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
AAAAAAAAA  | [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
AAAAAAAAAA | [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
```

Note the above example copies a region of the buffer's backing array, though the original `ByteBuffer` should be quickly garbage collected. The only way to avoid copying the backing array, that I can think of, is to adapt your code to work with the `ByteBuffer` directly (if you only return the backing array, you lose the position/limit information). Or I suppose you could create a wrapper class.